# AngularJs code on How can i get data in a single Row

Tags: angularjs

I have some Data as Follow

```
app.controller('MailCtrls', function ($scope) {

    $scope.employee = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Anil Singh1',
        age: 30,
        web: 'www.code-sample.com'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Sunil Singh2',
        age: 25,
        web: 'www.code-sample.com'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Sushil3',
        age: 20,
        web: 'www.code-sample.com'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Aradhya4',
        age: 2,
        web: 'www.code-sample.com'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Reena5',
        age: 25,
        web: 'www.code-sample.com'
    }];

    $scope.GetData = function () {
        alert();
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.employee.length; i++) {
            var abc = $scope.employee[i];
            if (abc.name != null) {
                $scope.emailNames = abc.name;
                console.log($scope.emailNames);
            }
```

Here i need data as `Email=Anil Singh1,Sunil Singh2,Sushil3,Aradhya4,Reena5` In this format How can i get data in this format
But i am Getting data as:

Anil Singh1

Sunil Singh2

Sushil3

Aradhya4

Reena5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes in your code.
 1. initialization for `$scope.emailNames` was missing.
 2. `console.log` statement was in loop.
 3. Instead of appending `+=` to the string, you were overriding it `=`.

```js
angular.module("myapp", []).controller('MailCtrls', function($scope) {

  $scope.employee = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Anil Singh1',
    age: 30,
    web: 'www.code-sample.com'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sunil Singh2',
    age: 25,
    web: 'www.code-sample.com'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sushil3',
    age: 20,
    web: 'www.code-sample.com'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Aradhya4',
    age: 2,
    web: 'www.code-sample.com'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Reena5',
    age: 25,
    web: 'www.code-sample.com'
  }];

  $scope.GetData = function() {
    $scope.emailNames = "Email=";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employee.length; i++) {
      var abc = $scope.employee[i];
      if (abc.name != null) {
        $scope.emailNames += abc.name + ",";
      }
    }
    console.log($scope.emailNames.substring(0,$scope.emailNames.length-1));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MailCtrls" ng-init="GetData()">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back Im getting value as undefinedAnil Singh1,Sunil Singh2,Sushil3,Aradhya4,Reena5,

Comment: probably you missed this before loop `$scope.emailNames = "Email=";`.